# Is t_whatever a reserved name in the C standard or POSIX?

Tags: c, posix, reserved-words

As far as I know:

> an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use that begin
>   with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital
>   letter are reserved names
>
> In Posix: Names that end with ‘_t’ are reserved for additional type
>   names.
>
> In addition: The header file sys/stat.h reserves names prefixed with
>   ‘st_’ and ‘S_’.

Can we use "t_whatever" (e.g. t_node) to define our own types?

Comment: Refer to [Reserved Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html) from the glibc manual for more...

Comment: Thank you @devnull, question is quoted from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use `t_` as a prefix, that's not in any reserved space.

Personally I wouldn't *recommend* doing so, but that's mainly because I'm not convinced that having a prefix to make a type name more obviously a type name is a win, in very many cases.

I can't see that

```
t_node head;
```

is better than

```
node head;
```

In fact, I think the latter is more readable. It's very often the case that you see from usage immediately if a word is a type or variable name in C, in my opinion.

One objection might be that it can be unclear when using `sizeof`, for instance consider dynamically allocating a new node. Many people would write that as:

```
t_node *head = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
```

but I'm very set against that usage; I consider it better to avoid handing type names to `sizeof` whenever possible, and use the variable instead, thus "locking" the size to the destination type which is a good thing:

```
node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

Also, as usual, note that I would never write the first example exactly like that, since I think it makes `sizeof` look like a function. I always have a space:

```
t_node *head = malloc(sizeof (t_node));
```